# how to improve matlab code when the bottle neck is some MEX-file?

Tags: matlab

I'm not too familiar with matlab profiling tool. But since my matlab program takes too long to run I was advised to try profiling it. When I did it, I got the result that most of the running time (self time) is spent in a function that I didn't write in my code with the name: mupadmex(MEX-file) (which is called 17266 times). Is this means that I cannot do anything to improve the running time of my code?

Comment: You could probably try to reduce the number of calls to `mupadmex` by finding redundant calls.

Answer (score 1):

Three solutions without knowing more to this problem

**Reduce amount of call**

Just try to remove the amount of call of this mex function, maybe some of the calls are redundant?

**Know what it does**

Maybe you know what that function does and you could just write a more efficient way to do the same thing?

**Change that funciton**

If you can get hands of the code of that mex function, you could try to improve it yourself.

Comment: I don't know where this mex function is being called. I did not call it directly from my code and I don't know what it does. How can I know why it's being called or what it does ? - the profiler report does not refer me to code lines in my .m  file.

Comment: Then I guess you are doing something wrong. Usually the profiles shows all running processes which are called directly, e.g. you start `profile on`, then run `myscript` then `profile viewer`, then it shows all lines of `myscript and you can click into all lines to analyze subfunctions, also mex (however, only the mex call and not the compiled code ofc)

Comment: I did just that and what I got is:

Comment: I did just that and what I got is a table with the  function names,calls,total and self times. one of the functions in this list was a function with the name "mupadmex (MEX-file)" , which I didn't write in my code. when I clicked on this function and back on the calling functions I got finally to the matlab function erfi which I called in my code. I need this function in order to calculate some antiderivative for each element of a 3D array. I don't know to implement this erfi function by myself. Is there anyhow a way I can make it run faster ??